# I can't pass ang string value into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code but I can't pass the value of array variable **$component** which has the input data of string. What should I do?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit_tbl_grade'])){
                    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : array();
                        $component = $_POST['component'];
                        $sub_component_number = $_POST['sub_component_number'];
                        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                        $score = $_POST['score'];

                    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($id) ; $i++){
                        $record = "INSERT INTO tbl_grade(stud_id,subject_id,component,sub_component_number,component_value) VALUES ($id[$i],$subject[$i],$component[$i],$sub_component_number[$i],$score[$i])";
                        mysqli_query($db,$record);
                    }
                   } ?>
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/251311

Comment: What does the form html look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [How do I create arrays in HTML forms](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) and [print debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_code?oldformat=true#Print_debugging) to check your $_POST data first to ensure the structure of data is be known to you.

There are also two problems in the sample code:

1. Filter input and escape output

   You must escape input data to prevent SQL Injection attacks.
   Check out the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/251311 commented by @zerkms
2. The inserting values must be proper format.

   for example, If `tbl_grade.compoment` is defined as `varchar, You must enclose values with a quote, Check the following example.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `tbl_grade` ( `component` ) VALUES ("hello world");
   ```